# How to pass variable from one controller to another in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have one controller with variable like

```
NSString *str;
```

In same controller i am assigning `userId` in string `str`.

I need above `userId` in another controller to show user data.

How should I get value of `userId` in another controller?

Below is my code:

MainViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomatic) NSString *str;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@synthesize str;

str = 1;
```

Now in FirstViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomatic, retain) MainViewController *mainCon;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@synthesize mainCon;

NSLog(@"user id is %@", mainCon.str);
```

Here in log i am getting null value.

Comment: where u r allocated the firstViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be in the [prepareForSegue] method

within that method I usually have something like

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString@"segueName"]){
    //I use this if statement to check which segue I am performing, if I have multiple
    //segues from a single view controller
    FirstVc *newViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    newViewController.str = self.str;
}
```

This will pass the string from your main VC to your new VC.  This is all assuming that your transitions are laid out in Interface Builder or some way that gives you access to the segues and identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Take a Property in MainVC and Pass value from FirstVC then It will work for you.

the following code must be in MainVC

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *str; 
@synthesize str;
```

in FirstVC

```
MainVC * vc = [[MainVC alloc]init];
vc.str = @"test";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:**

You have to create a **viewcontroller**  class as **Constants**

**Step 2:**

You can delete **.m** file in **Constanst** class

**Step3:**

You have to import the **Constants.h** in **Projectname_Prefix.pch** which will be xcode's in other resources folder. Now Constant class will act as global class.

**Step4:**

Now, you can declare variables in **Constants.h**. The variables those declared in **Constants.h** will  act as global variable. you can access it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondViewController.str1 = str;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

It's a quicker and easy solution.